# Connection String Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

So I have been thinking about how to make my life easier by automating the connection string name used to connect to my databases. I program on my laptop and on a PC at work. They utilize different databases. So I created the code below and it’s working. However, I don’t recall ever hearing about this method before and am wondering why? Is this a bad way to do this sort of thing. Understandably, I have to remove the code before releasing it but it sure seems like it’d make it easier to switch between computers since I don’t have to comment/uncomment lines in Web.config. Each connection string name is set to the computer name in Web.config.

```
static string connectionStringName = System.Environment.MachineName;

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(connectionStringName, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A different approach to consider would be leveraging [web.config transforms](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) and create new environments (Dev-PC / Dev-Laptop) which contains has a different connection strings you need.

Then when you launch Visual Studio, you can simply select the build profile you need and when you launch the app the appropriate connection strings will be used. This will be helpful if you need to use file paths or other configurations that will differ between the two environments.

Comment: Thanks, Dillie-O. To be honest I don’t really have a clear understanding of web transforms that’s why I was looking for something easier.

Comment: I really recommend against using web.config transforms on their own - they force you to rebuild your package every time you deploy to a new target environment, which starts to get REALLY cumbersome when you bring automated release processes into the mix.

Comment: @physics90 - If it helps at all with the confusion of web.config transforms, here's an old blog post I wrote on how to get it up and running, which is a lot easier than it sounds - https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/tame-your-configurationdeployments-with-web-config-transforms/

s3raph86 makes a good point about deployment concerns, but I've found in my own CI environments that Kudu / Azure / VS makes it easy to target the proper config at compilation for deployment. You may need to revisit that, but if you're mainly concerned with your own dev work, transforms should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is to use a combination of web.config transforms, and your SetParameters.xml file. I know that they can seem daunting at first, but if you invest the time into learning, it pays off.

Using web.config transforms, or naming your connection strings based on machine names is a **Bad Idea TM**. These solutions *will* work, but they require you to rebuild your WebDeploy package every time you release to a new environment. You want a solution that lets you deploy any package to any environment.

Firstly you'll need to create two web.config transforms. One for Debug, and one for Release. Web.Debug.config will look something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=MyDevDatabase;Integrated Security=True" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Whereas your Web.Release.config will contain a placeholder string. These placeholders will be updated when you deploy your package into IIS in your target environment. It should look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" connectionString="__targetenvironmentconnstring__" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

To get your target environment connection string in place when you do your deploy, you need to update your publish profiles under *Properties* in your web project. You'll create one publish profile (using the *Package* option) for each target environment; so QA.pubxml, UAT.pubxml, Production.pubxml, etc. Visual Studio will walk you through a wizard to create these files when you use the *Publish* dialog. Now open each file. You'll want to edit the end of the file to incorporate `MSDeployParameterValue` elements like I've done here

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup> <!-- A bunch of info --> </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)MyDB-Web.config Connection String">
    <ParameterValue><!-- Your target environment connection string goes here! --></ParameterValue>
  </MSDeployParameterValue>
</Project>
```

Now right-click and Publish on your web project, selecting the publish profile you want. In the output directory you've specified, you'll see a SetParameters.xml file which contains your target connection string. This is what will go into your web.config file when you deploy, but crucially, you can also just import the package manually using IIS, and assign your own values at deploy time like this:

[image]

Finally you can just refer to your connection string using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString` and you've got the correct value, no matter what environment you're in!

To understand more, I highly recommend reading the following

- https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment
- https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages

It takes a few goes to wrap your head around, but you'll never go back.